# Turn Dynamics 365 address field into dropdown list

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I’m new to both Dynamics 365 and javascript.

By now users when have to fill an address form write values manually, therefore for the same region we have values like: Lombardia, LOMABARDIA, lomb, Lombadia, etc...

I can't create custom fields because address fields are grouped into composite field and are used for outlook sync.

So i think the right way is create a javascript mask that paste the choosen value in the free text address field, but here is my biggest problem, how to set that mask...

Questions:

Is this the best practice? if not what is?

I am able to create javascript's list and get/set value from crm, but i dont know how to build it over a free text field, any help?

Comment: Thanks for your question. TIP: It is not necessary to say that you are new to the topic of your question as that is not relevant information.

Comment: To improve this question and get an answer, please, put some code sample and screenshots of your program.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider address resolution API, you will then be able to split the selected address that will be in a standard format. Try to check out Experian or even the google API, you can build a custom web resource, hook up the JS that will do address resolution for you, on selection split the values in the composite fields.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "build it over a free text field", which is unsupported, you can build your own custom HTML web resource and add that to the form.

As [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webpage-html-web-resources#reference-other-web-resources-from-an-html-web-resource) points out, you will need to use `parent.Xrm.Page` to reference the form - e.g.:

`var customerRef = parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute('customerid').getValue();`

[This forum](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/302221) indicates that although `Xrm.Page` is deprecated in v9, it is still valid (for now) to use `parent.Xrm.Page` from a custom web resource.

Also, please note that to enable accessing the form you should include
`<script type="text/javascript" src="../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx"></script>`
in your custom web resource.

Comment: thank you this would be a good solution, i can built it and a workflow will copy the value into the otb field that i need for outlook sync. I'll update this answer.